# How to develop different form pages if they have a common section inside of theirself?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, forms

Let's say I have 5 different forms and these forms have a common section plus a form-specific section. The common section includes name input, surname input and similar things, and form-specific sections are different inputs depends on forms.

At this point, I though that I can create ONE form page which has a common section, and form-specific sections are rendered depends on a route address.  However, I am not sure about this approach. Because I can also develop 5 different form pages. I do not know which approach is the better one.

So, How do you develop these kind of forms?